# Fetch data from json file and show it to DataTable - Angular2

Tags: angular, web, frontend, jscript

I am new in Angular2 and can't solve next issue.I'll be appreciated for your help.
I have some data in data.json file :

```
[ 
 {
   "name": "Jayme",
   "email": "a.nunc.In@convallisante.ca",
    "regDate": "2016-02-07T10:22:09-08:00",
    "city": "Ville de Maniwaki",
    "age": 30
  },
  {
    "name": "Bo",
    "email": "posuere.cubilia.Curae@estNunclaoreet.net",
    "regDate": "2016-08-16T20:42:44-07:00",
    "city": "Pak Pattan",
    "age": 24
  },
  {
    "name": "Matthew",
    "email": "enim.Mauris.quis@vehicula.edu",
    "regDate": "2015-05-01T01:53:59-07:00",
    "city": "Alacant",
    "age": 35
  },
  {
    "name": "Justina",
    "email": "Donec.nibh@Vivamusmolestie.ca",
    "regDate": "2015-06-24T14:38:07-07:00",
    "city": "Kobbegem",
    "age": 22
  }
]
```

This is my sit_log.component.ts

```
import { Component,OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from "@angular/http";

@Component({
  selector: 'sit_log',
  templateUrl: './sit_log.html'
})
export class SIT_log implements OnInit{

  public data;
  public filterQuery = "";
  public rowsOnPage = 10;
  public sortBy = "email";
  public sortOrder = "asc";

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(window.location.href);

    this.http.get("http://localhost:4200/index.html#/pages/sit_log/data.json")
        .subscribe((data)=> {
            setTimeout(()=> {
                this.data = data.json();
            }, 1000);
        });
   }

}
```

When I run the code I receive next error :

```
core.es5.js:1084 ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
at Object.parse (<anonymous>)
at Response.Body.json (http.es5.js:800)
at SafeSubscriber._next (sit_log.component.ts:23)
at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:238)
at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:185)
at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:125)
at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:89)
at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http.es5.js:1229)
at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.688.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:424)
at Object.onInvokeTask (core.es5.js:4140)
```

Have anybody some idea?
Regards.

Comment: Trim the space in front of the content in `data.json`

Comment: @OluwafemiSule i don't  think this cause any error in the app

Comment: @evgeny try using `console.log(data)` before assigning , i think you are getting JSON format data and you are again parsing it into JSON format

Comment: the "url" looks a bit weird to me... ?

Comment: need to place @Injectable() above @Component.

Comment: @kkpatel, that's not true, we are not injecting this class anywhere.

Comment: @Evgeny did the issue get sorted ?

Comment: Thanks for all your response:) I replaced data.json file to assets/data directive and all works fine. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your response:)
I replaced data.json file to assets/data directive and all works fine.
Thanks again :)